# Passing a vector as the times argument to rep in R

Tags: r, boolean, truthtable, rep

I'm creating the input structure of binary truth tables for a Boolean network modeling project. Each node in the network of size *n* may have a different number of inputs *k*, resulting in truth tables of varying dimensions.

I'm using the following bit of code:

`replicate(n, expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),times=k)), simplify=FALSE)`

which works appropriately if *n* and *k* have fixed values.

For instance, in the case of n = 3 and k = 2, I get three 4x4 matrices of 0s and 1s. This is a useful result.

My goal is to do something similar with the fixed *k* replaced by a numerical vector of length *n* such that each element in the vector represents the number of inputs in a corresponding network node.

For example, if `n = 3` and `x <- c(2, 3, 2)`, I would pass x as an argument and the output would be 3 matrices of dimensions 4x4, 8x8, and 4x4.

Using my existing code, when I define k as a vector and attempt to use it as the *times* argument I find that its invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to change `k` each time, you should make a function with `k` as a parameter and then you can apply over it (rather than `replicate`). For example

```
ks <- c(2, 3, 2)
lapply(ks, function(k) expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),times=k)))
```

We don't really need `n` here since presumably that's just whatever the length of the vector of `k` values is.